# What is a basis function in spline regression?

Tags: regression, spline

I'm learning about spline regression right now and there's this notation of basis function.

$$f(X)=\sum^M_{m=1}B_mh_m(X)$$

This is the notation using is *The Elements of Statistical Learning - Data Mining, Inference and Prediction.* $B_m$ seems to be the function that's defined in that interval and they write basis functions are $h_1(X)=I(X<\epsilon_1)$ where $\epsilon_1$ is a knot. I'm having trouble understanding what a basis function is and what $f(X)$ is.

Comment: Are you familiar with basis vectors from linear algebra? These functions are exactly that and $f(X)$ is a linear combination of those basis vectors. These vectors just happen to be functions.

Comment: @CyclotomicField no I'm not familiar with basis functions are. Also do you know what $\mathbf{I}(X<\epsilon_1)$ is supposed to be?

Comment: A simple example of a function basis is for quadratic polynomials with basis functions $1, x$ and $x^2$. Linear combinations of those functions are of the form $ax^2 + bx + c$.